# Kernel Module Programming ( Interrupt handler )

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I write a simple kernel module example about how to use interrupt handler. The module services keyboard interrupts. It reads the relevant information from the keyboard and then puts information about Key that pressed. It successfully insmod module into the kernel, and interrupt work well.
However, when I do rmmod module, the LED on Caps Lock blinking and my PC is frozen (I run it on Vmware machine). I think I have the bugs in __exit function. But I do not know how to fix. Can anyone help me? Thank you so much.
The code:

```
/*
* An interrupt handler
*/

#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/workqueue.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <asm/io.h>


MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Hai Dang Hoang");

/*
*   This function services keyboard interrupts. It reads the relevant
*   information from the keyboard and then puts information about Key that pressed
*   This example only has 3 key: ESC, F1, and F2
*/

irqreturn_t irq_handler(int irq, void *dev_id, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
/*
* This variables are static because they need to be
* accessible (through pointers) to the bottom half routine.
*/

  static unsigned char scancode;
  unsigned char status;

/*
* Read keyboard status
*/
  status = inb(0x64);
  scancode = inb(0x60);

switch (scancode)
{
  case 0x01:  printk (KERN_INFO "! You pressed Esc ...\n");
              break;
  case 0x3B:  printk (KERN_INFO "! You pressed F1 ...\n");
              break;
  case 0x3C:  printk (KERN_INFO "! You pressed F2 ...\n");
              break;
  default:
              break;
}

  return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

/*
* Initialize the module - register the IRQ handler
*/
static int __init irq_ex_init(void)
{
    /* Free interrupt*/
    free_irq(1,NULL);
    return request_irq (1, (irq_handler_t) irq_handler,IRQF_SHARED, "test_keyboard_irq_handler",(void *)(irq_handler));
}

static void __exit irq_ex_exit(void)
{
    free_irq(1,NULL);
}

module_init(irq_ex_init);
module_exit(irq_ex_exit);
```

Or you can see my code on my link GitHub: [Example interrupt handler](https://github.com/danghai/Kernel/blob/master/irq_handler/irq_ex1.c)

Comment: I'm interested to know how you executed rmmod command, since your module's handler won't support alphabet inputs.

Comment: what do you mean alphabet inputs?

Comment: you have removed the builtin keyboard module in your init function, now your module alone is responsibe for keyboard interrrupts.
Since your module's interrupt handler is implemented for ESC, F1 and F2, how the terminal is taking input for "rmmod", I'm very new to device drivers please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 2):

Your example does not handle some random IRQ. It handles an interrupt critical for working with the machine.

At the beginning of your registration you remove the previous interrupt handler. Your problem is that you failed to re-install it once you remove your own.

The result is that, when you `rmmod` your module, no one is handling the keyboard interrupt.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? Can you write the fixed code? I appreciate it

Comment: @HaiDang I'm not sure there is a simple way of checking who the current handler is. Without it, it is not simple to write the code you need. I suggest you look for an unused interrupt for your learning project.

Comment: @"Hai Dang" - as stated by @"Shachar Shemesh" once you used the free_irq of the keyboard IRQ you can't restore it and you must reboot your system. Please see the source of your code which explain this: https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/Linux_Kernel_Module_Programming_Guide/x1236.html

Answer (score 0):

Please change the code:

```
static void __exitrq_ex_exit(void) 
{
     free_irq(1, NULL);
}
```

into:

```
static void __exitrq_ex_exit(void) 
{
     free_irq(1, (void*)irq_handler);
}
```

You need to let the kernel know which handler you want to remove. Since you use the function `irq_handler()` as the `dev_id`, you need to use it again to remove the mode without remove the original keyboard interrupt handler.